# Do Java compiler warnings affect compile time?

Tags: java, performance, compilation, compiler-warnings

I've got a legacy project with several thousand compiler warnings (raw types, unnecessary @SuppressWarnings, unused imports etc) - the project has about 5000 Java source files. Are these warnings likely to have any significant impact on the compile time?

Please note: **I am well aware that getting rid of compiler warnings *just* to improve performance is not a good reason for doing so. I'd love to get rid of the warnings to make it easier to add new code, reduce potential bugs etc. But in this case, all I'm asking is if the compilation process takes longer if there are large numbers of warnings.**

Comment: Why is compile time necessary in your case?

Comment: Is the compile time unacceptably long? Does it decrease if you fix some of them?

Comment: Logically, it will make a little difference, if the compiling is optimized based on annotation. If the compilation code is filtering warnings based on annotation, i.e. find all the warnings and ignore the ones with annotation ,it will not make significant difference.

Comment: @AndyTurner Yes, the compile time is unacceptably long (in the region of 60s). It's hard to measure the improvement, as I can only automatically fix the unused imports, the others need to be fixed on a warning-by-warning basis which is pretty tedious. I was hoping for a definitive yes/no as to whether it's worth pursuing.

Comment: @QmunkE what about generating 5000 random classes without any compiler errors (and a similar degree of interdependence), and seeing if the compile time is similar.

Comment: Compared to the cost of maintainability, it hardly matters.  If you computer is kept cool so it can stay at top speed, it run faster. i.e. the temperature of the machine probably matters more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No; not significantly. The value of addressing compiler warnings comes from reducing project maintenance time, i.e., the programmer's time, not from the time it takes to compile. By addressing these warnings you will have a clearer picture of what's going awry instead of getting lost in a sea of warnings...

Comment: I understand that this is the case, but this doesn't answer my question. At the moment I'm trying to improve the build time in any way I can (it's unacceptably slow, and any incremental improvement will lead to an improved quality of life during development)

Comment: @QmunkE -- if your build time is unacceptably long, and you're asking if addressing warning will fix that, the answer is "no". Fixing the warnings may improve your build time by some small amount, but the real issues behind your long build time will still be there. My answer simply reflects this mis-understanding. You might consider asking for help with your build time, rather than this narrow question about warnings...

Comment: I know there are plenty of other, more impactful ways to improve the build time - it's a question of whether doing this will have any impact at all - if the answer is "no" then it's "no", but your answer isn't helpful - it doesn't answer the question. I'm well aware of why having thousands of compiler warnings is bad from a maintenance point of view.

Comment: I'll rephrase to make it more understandable, @QmunkE.

Comment: It's not about being understandable, it's literally asking whether there is a measurable impact on compilation time if your code contains warnings vs whether it doesn't. I don't care if there are other benefits to having fewer warnings (I already know this), or whether there are other, better ways to improve compile time (I know this as well).

Answer (score 0):

> Are these warnings likely to have any significant impact on the
>   compile time?

No.

In a comment to Jans answer you wrote

> it's literally asking whether there is a measurable impact on
>   compilation time if your code contains warnings vs whether it doesn't

Yes, there will be a measurable impact but it's likely to be very very small. This comment makes me think you're asking two different questions?

Jans answer, at least to me is absolutely correct.

Comment: Jans' answer is certainly true. But it was originally not a helpful answer at all - it addressed a different reason for getting rid of warnings (which is in general more important, just not helpful in my case). The key line in my question is this: "Are these warnings likely to have any significant impact on the compile time?" - that is all I wanted to know. Not sure why this is so difficult to get across.